# WHERE CASE WHEN THEN statement with Exists

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, case, exists

How to write it correctly:

```
declare @p7_ int
set @p7_=1
select * from cdn.tranag
    where  
    case when @p7_=1 then 
    exists(select * from cdn.zrodla join cdn.dziennik on dzk_gidnumer=zro_dtnumer where TrN_GIDTyp=zro_trntyp and TrN_GIDNumer=zro_trnnumer) 
    else -1 end
```

Thanks.

Comment: Add some sample table data, and the expected result. (As well formatted text.) And tag the dbms you're using.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve ?

Comment: If parameter = 1 then exists. If the parameter = 0 then show all

Answer (score 0):

The `where` clause in SQL needs to be comparing something to something else.  It looks like you are simply trying to say "bring back everything unless `@p7_` has the value `1`, in which case check that records exist elsewhere."

You can achieve this using simple logical operators such as `and` and `or` in your `where` clause:

```
select columns
from table
where @p7_ <> 1
   or (@p7_ = 1
       and exists(<exists statement>)
      )
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be achieved through `AND/OR` logic.

You are looking for this

```
SELECT *
FROM   cdn.Tranag
WHERE  ( @p7_ = 1
         AND EXISTS(SELECT *
                    FROM   cdn.zrodla
                           JOIN cdn.dziennik
                             ON dzk_gidnumer = zro_dtnumer
                    WHERE  TrN_GIDTyp = zro_trntyp
                           AND TrN_GIDNumer = zro_trnnumer) )
        OR @p7_ = 0
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you want:

```
select *
from cdn.tranag t
where (@p7_= 1 and
       exists (select 1
               from cdn.zrodla join
                    cdn.dziennik
                    on dzk_gidnumer = zro_dtnumer
               where t.TrN_GIDTyp = zro_trntyp and
                     t.TrN_GIDNumer = zro_trnnumer
              )
      ) or
      (@p7_ <> 1);
```

This implements the logic that if `@p7_ = 1` then the `exists` clause is checked.  Otherwise, all rows are chosen.  Note:  This doesn't check for `NULL`, but that is easy to add.

Also, note the use of table aliases.  You should always use table aliases, especially when you are using subqueries and especially when you have multiple tables.

Answer (score 0):

A bit of side info:

In T-Sql, `EXISTS` is a boolean expression with a `true/false` result. However unlike many other languages, `true/false` "values" in T-Sql don't map to integer values. In other words you can never treat a T-Sql *boolean expression result* as an `INT` value. They can only be used in bool clauses such as `WHERE ...`, `JOIN ON ...`, `IF ...` and `CASE WHEN ...`.